# ParallelCurl no longer working after upgrade from PHP 5.3 to 5.5

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04.  With the upgrade, PHP went from 5.3 to 5.5.  One of my applications uses PHP and the ParallelCurl class written by Pete Warden.  Unfortunately the last update to the class was 2 years ago according to his website.

After the upgrade, when I run my script, each request ends up in what appears to be an infinite loop of the private function waitForOutstandingRequestsToDropBelow($max).  Can anyone see why the upgrade is causing this issue?

parallelcurl.php

```
<?php
class ParallelCurl {

public $max_requests;
public $options;

public $outstanding_requests;
public $multi_handle;

public function __construct($in_max_requests = 10, $in_options = array()) {
    $this->max_requests = $in_max_requests;
    $this->options = $in_options;

    $this->outstanding_requests = array();
    $this->multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
}

//Ensure all the requests finish nicely
public function __destruct() {
    $this->finishAllRequests();
}

// Sets how many requests can be outstanding at once before we block and wait for one to
// finish before starting the next one
public function setMaxRequests($in_max_requests) {
    $this->max_requests = $in_max_requests;
}

// Sets the options to pass to curl, using the format of curl_setopt_array()
public function setOptions($in_options) {

    $this->options = $in_options;
}

// Start a fetch from the $url address, calling the $callback function passing the optional
// $user_data value. The callback should accept 3 arguments, the url, curl handle and user
// data, eg on_request_done($url, $ch, $user_data);
public function startRequest($url, $callback, $user_data = array(), $post_fields=null) {

    if( $this->max_requests > 0 )
        $this->waitForOutstandingRequestsToDropBelow($this->max_requests);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $this->options);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    if (isset($post_fields)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($this->multi_handle, $ch);

    $ch_array_key = (int)$ch;

    $this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key] = array(
        'url' => $url,
        'callback' => $callback,
        'user_data' => $user_data,
    );

    $this->checkForCompletedRequests();
}

// You *MUST* call this function at the end of your script. It waits for any running requests
// to complete, and calls their callback functions
public function finishAllRequests() {
    $this->waitForOutstandingRequestsToDropBelow(1);
}

// Checks to see if any of the outstanding requests have finished
private function checkForCompletedRequests() {

    // Call select to see if anything is waiting for us
    if (curl_multi_select($this->multi_handle, 0.0) === -1)
        return;

    // Since something's waiting, give curl a chance to process it
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    // Now grab the information about the completed requests
    while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($this->multi_handle)) {

        $ch = $info['handle'];
        $ch_array_key = (int)$ch;

        if (!isset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key])) {
            die("Error - handle wasn't found in requests: '$ch' in ".
                print_r($this->outstanding_requests, true));
        }

        $request = $this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key];

        $url = $request['url'];
        $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
        $callback = $request['callback'];
        $user_data = $request['user_data'];

        call_user_func($callback, $content, $url, $ch, $user_data);

        unset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key]);

        curl_multi_remove_handle($this->multi_handle, $ch);
    }

}

// Blocks until there's less than the specified number of requests outstanding
private function waitForOutstandingRequestsToDropBelow($max)
{
    while (1) {
        $this->checkForCompletedRequests();
        if (count($this->outstanding_requests)<$max)
            break;

        usleep(10000);
    }
}

}


?>
```

Comment: Use [Rolling Curl](https://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/) instead. Or its advanced fork [Rolling Curl Mini](https://github.com/hindmost/rolling-curl-mini) (plug!).